Problema con herencia múltiple: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument
Estoy estudiando python, así que estoy preparado para que el error sea una estupidez y quedarme con cara de tonto, pero llevo demasiado tiempo intentando solucionarlo como para que me importe ya. El código es el siguiente:
class Instrumento():
    #Constructor
    def __init__(self,tamaño, precio, material):
        self.__tamaño = tamaño
        self.__precio = precio
        self.__material = material
        
    #Getters y setters
    @property
    def tamaño(self):
        return self.__tamaño
    @tamaño.setter
    def tamaño(self, nuevo):
        self.__tamaño = nuevo

    @property
    def precio(self):
        return self.__precio
    @precio.setter
    def precio(self, nuevo):
        self.__precio = nuevo

    @property
    def material(self):
        return self.__material
    @material.setter
    def material(self, nuevo):
        self.__material = nuevo
        
    #Métodos
    def sonido(self):
        print("Se reproducirá el sonido del instrumento:")
        print("<Imaginar sonido aquí>") #Idealmente el metodo serviria para reproducir un archivo de sonido
        
    def __str__(self):
        return """El instrumento tiene las siguientes características:
        >>> tamaño {}
        >>> precio de {}€
        >>> hecho de {}""".format(self.__tamaño, self.__precio, self.__material)

class InsViento(Instrumento):
    #Constructor
    def __init__(self, tamaño, precio, material, num_llaves):
        super().__init__(tamaño, precio, material)
        self.__num_llaves = num_llaves

    #Getters y setters
    @property
    def num_llaves(self):
        return self.__num_llaves
    @num_llaves.setter
    def num_llaves(self, nuevo):
        self__num_llaves = nuevo

    #Métodos
    def sonido(self):
        print("Se reproducirá el sonido del instrumento:")
        print("<Placeholder sonido trompeta>")

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + """
        >>> tiene {} llaves""".format(self.__num_llaves)

class InsCuerda(Instrumento):
    #Constructor
    def __init__(self, tamaño, precio, material, num_cuerdas):
        super().__init__(tamaño, precio, material)
        self.__num_cuerdas = num_cuerdas

    #Getters y setters
    @property
    def num_cuerdas(self):
        return self.__num_cuerdas
    @num_cuerdas.setter
    def num_cuerdas(self, nuevo):
        self__num_cuerdas = nuevo

    #Métodos
    def sonido(self):
        print("Se reproducirá el sonido del instrumento:")
        print("<Placeholder sonido guitarra>")

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + """
        >>> tiene {} cuerdas""".format(self.__num_cuerdas)

class InsPercusion(Instrumento):
    #Constructor
    def __init__(self, tamaño, precio, material, baqueta):
        super().__init__(tamaño, precio, material)
        self.__baqueta = baqueta

    #Getters y setters
    @property
    def baqueta(self):
        return self.__baqueta
    @baqueta.setter
    def baqueta(self, nuevo):
        self__baqueta = nuevo

    #Métodos
    def sonido(self):
        print("Se reproducirá el sonido del instrumento:")
        print("<Placeholder sonido bateria>")

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + """
        >>> baqueta tipo {}""".format(self.__baqueta)

class InsCuerdaPercutida(InsCuerda, InsPercusion):
    #Constructor
    def __init__(self, tamaño, precio, material, num_cuerdas, tipo, baqueta=None):
        InsPercusion.__init__(self, tamaño, precio, material, baqueta)
        InsCuerda.__init__(self, tamaño, precio, material, num_cuerdas)
        self.__tipo = tipo

    #Getters y setters
    @property
    def tipo(self):
        return self.__tipo
    @tipo.setter
    def tipo(self, nuevo):
        self.__tipo = nuevo

    #Métodos
    def sonido(self):
        print("Se reproducirá el sonido del instrumento:")
        print("<Placeholder sonido piano>")

    def __str__(self):
        if self.__baqueta == None:
            return InsCuerda.__str__(self) + """
        >>> tipo {}""".format(self.__tipo)
        else:
            return InsPercusion.__str__(self) + """
            >>> tiene {} cuerdas
        >>> tipo {}""".format(self.__num_cuerdas, self.__tipo)

trompeta = InsViento("mediano", 50, "metal", 4)
guitarra = InsCuerda("mediano-grande", 150, "madera", 5)
bateria = InsPercusion("grande", 500, "metal", "punta de madera")
piano = InsCuerdaPercutida("grande", 1500, "madera", 70, "piano de cola", "martillo")

Se pueden ignorar las primeras clases ya que el error solo se da en el objeto "piano", que al intentar crear me salta el siguiente error:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[161], line 142
140 guitarra = InsCuerda("mediano-grande", 150, "madera", 5)
141 bateria = InsPercusion("grande", 500, "metal", "punta de madera")
--> 142 piano = InsCuerdaPercutida("grande", 1500, "madera", 70, "piano de cola", "martillo")
144 #Pruebas
145 bateria.sonido()

Cell In[161], line 114, in InsCuerdaPercutida.__init__(self, tamaño, precio, material, 
num_cuerdas, tipo, baqueta)
112 def __init__(self, tamaño, precio, material, num_cuerdas, tipo, baqueta=None):
113     InsPercusion.__init__(self, tamaño, precio, material, baqueta)
--> 114     InsCuerda.__init__(self, tamaño, precio, material, num_cuerdas)
115     self.__tipo = tipo

Cell In[161], line 67, in InsCuerda.__init__(self, tamaño, precio, material, num_cuerdas)
 66 def __init__(self, tamaño, precio, material, num_cuerdas):
---> 67     super().__init__(tamaño, precio, material)
 68     self.__num_cuerdas = num_cuerdas

TypeError: InsPercusion.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'baqueta'

Además de pasar el argumento, le he puesto un valor por defecto para que sea opcional, aun así da el error. También me extraña que las flechas del Traceback señalen otra parte del proceso. Los demás objetos se crean y funcionan correctamente, así que según entiendo el problema es que el valor de "baqueta" no llega a la clase padre, pero no consigo entender porqué.
Gracias de antemano.

Ahora sabes porque nadie usa herencia múltiple en Python. Entre otros problemas, estas inicializado dos veces la clase base, lo cual puede tener efectos secundarios. En general se recomienda usar "composición" en lugar de "herencia".

Tu error es una muestra clásica del problema del diamante en herencia múltiple, problema que todo lenguaje que la soporta tiene que resolver de alguna manera. Python lo resuelve realizando una linealización o "aplanamiento" del MRO a través de super, usalo en vez de llama explicitamente a los inicializadores y haz que las clases cooperen entre si, mirate la pregunta duplicada y si tienes problema comenta. La herencia múltiples es problemática en general, no solo en Python, por eso mucha gente huye de ella como la peste como comenta Candid Moe.

Un par de observaciones, no uses foo == None, None es un singleton, usa foo is None / foo is not None. Segundo, te aconsejo no usar el name mangling (doble underscore) para denotar variables o métodos "privados", ni sirve ni se pensó para eso, es confuso e induce a errores, aún así lo ves en tutoriales y demás mal explicado y aplicado.... Usa un solo guión en todo caso. Es más, si tus properties no hacen nada más que asignar/retornar el atributo "privado" sin realizar algún procesado intermedio no las uses, permite el acceso directo al atributo y olvidate de los setters/getters.

Te dejo tu código con algunas de estas modificaciones para que compares y ejecutes online si quieres: https://godbolt.org/z/ddTYzjv91 Además tiene los cambios necesarios para solventar tu problema original, que están explicados en mi respuesta a la duplicada, además en ella muestro otra opción forzando el uso de argumentos por palabra clave para los argumentos especificas de cada subclase y que personalmente me gusta más, pero que requiere más cambios a tu código original.

Ya me he mirado la respuesta duplicada así como las modificaciones del ejemplo, definitivamente empezaré a utilizar*args y **kwargs en caso de que tenga que utilizar herencia múltiple. También me he fijado que has modificado los __str__, supongo que para solucionar el hecho de que los string multilinea devuelven los espacios y tabulaciones a los print como si fueran parte  del código. Muchas gracias por el tiempo y esfuerzo empleados @FJSevilla.

@ArnauCastello Si, lo de las cadenas de los __str__ es una concatenacion (implícita) de literales de cadena y es principalmente  para evitar lo que comentas y por legibilidad. No obstante hay otras forma de eliminar la identacion del código en los strings multilinea sin tener que cargarte la identación del código.  Por cierto, si quieres profundizar en super y el MRO y el inglés no es un problema la charla de la PyCon 2015 de Raymond Hettinger puede ser interesante: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo
